# Why I get error when I load XML file with XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, dtd, xmldocument

I've a XML file like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget &xyz me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Here say &xyz is an entity which is declared in the Note.dtd file. But when I try this it gives me an error - Reference to undeclared entity 'xyz'.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);  // Error is thrown at this line
```

Does XmlDocument doesn't check the external referred dtds ? How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Is the DTD in the right place? What does the content of this file look like?

Comment: shouldn't that be `&xyz;` with a semicolon at the end to be valid?

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 1):

To load an XmlDocument and validate against the DTD and resolve entities you need to configure the XmlReader to validate.

Here is an example that works with your XML file

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace DtdValidation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
            settings.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml", settings);
            doc.Load(reader);
        }

        // Display any validation errors.
        private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validation Error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DTD I used, which declares the `xyz` entity

```
<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY xyz "->">
```

---

***Original Answer - I initially misread the question***

The `&` is a special character in XML so when you want to include a literal & you need to encode it using `&amp;`
Here are the other encodings you might encounter

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
& &amp
" &quot;
' &apos;
```